NestJS Mongoose Pre - Post Hooks
import { Prop, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose, { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';
import { mongoSchemaBase } from 'src/common/decorators';
import {
  Form,
} from 'src/modules/form/entities/form.entity';

export type FeedbackDocument = HydratedDocument<Feedback>;

@mongoSchemaBase()
export class Feedback {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  comment: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Form' })
  formID: Form;

  @Prop({ default: true })
  isActive: boolean;
}

export const FeedbackSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Feedback);

import { Prop, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose, { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';
import { mongoSchemaBase } from 'src/common/decorators';
import { Course } from 'src/modules/course/entities/course.entity';
import { Feedback } from 'src/modules/feedback/entities/feedback.entity';

export type FormDocument = HydratedDocument<Form>;

@mongoSchemaBase()
export class Form {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  fullName: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  phoneNumber: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  question: string;

  @Prop({
    type: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: Course.name, default: [] }],
  })
  courseIDs: [Course];

  @Prop({
    type: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: Feedback.name, default: [] }],
  })
  feedbackIDs: [Feedback];

  @Prop({ default: true })
  isActive: boolean;
}

export const FormSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Form);


// Pre-save hook to perform actions before saving a Feedback document
FeedbackSchema.pre('save', async function (next: Function) {
  if (!this.isNew) {
    return next(); // Skip if not a new document
  }
  // Add any pre-save logic here if needed
  next();
});

// Post-save hook to update the Form document after saving a Feedback document
FeedbackSchema.post(
  'save',
  async function (doc: FeedbackDocument, next: Function) {
    try {
      const FormModel = mongoose.model('form', FormSchema); // Get the Form model
      await FormModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: doc.formID },
        { $push: { feedbacks: doc._id } },
      ); // Add the feedback to the Form's feedbacks array

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  },
);

NestJS Moongose, i cant apply pre and post hooks, while trying it just goes to the error that buffering timeouted out 10000ms
I tried, using pre post inside forRootAsync, inside entity files, nothing works.
[Nest] 25088  - 08/01/2024, 1:04:37 AM   ERROR MongooseError: Operation forms.findOneAndUpdate() buffering timed out after 10000ms
Here is the error i encounter

// Pre-save hook to perform actions before saving a Feedback document
FeedbackSchema.pre('save', async function (next: Function) {
  if (!this.isNew) {
    return next(); // Skip if not a new document
  }

  const FormModel = mongoose.model('Form', FormSchema); // Get the Form model

  const formId = this.formID; // Get the form ID from the Feedback document

  // Find the Form document using the form ID
  const form = await FormModel.findById(formId);

  if (!form) {
    return next(new BadRequestException('Form not found'));
  }

  next();
});


// Post-save hook to update the Form document after saving a Feedback document
FeedbackSchema.post(
'save',
async function (doc: FeedbackDocument, next: Function) {
try {
const FormModel = mongoose.model('Form', FormSchema); // Get the Form model
console.log(' ~ FormModel:', FormModel);
  next();
} catch (error) {
  next(error);
}

},
);
